# Virtual Class Properties Not Returned from Apex to Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, inheritance

I'm seeing that public fields from an Apex base virtual class are not returned to a lightning controller. The Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class MyApexController {

    public virtual class MyVirtualClass {

        @Auraenabled
        public Boolean fromVirtual {get; set;}           
    }

    public class ParentClass extends MyVirtualClass {
        @Auraenabled
        public Boolean testField {get; set;}

        public ParentClass() {
            this.fromVirtual = false;
            this.testField = false;
        }
    }

    @Auraenabled
    public static ParentClass getParentClass() {
        return new ParentClass();
    }
}
```

When I call `getParentClass` from a lightning component I was expecting to get:

```
{
    fromVirtual: false,
    testField: false
}
```

But I get

```
{
    testField: false
}
```

I've tried `public virtual class MyVirtualClass` and `public with sharing virtual class MyVirtualClass` both with the same result. Note also that AuraEnabled is not allowed on classes.